# Expression Tree for Enumerable.Select

Tags: c#, expression-trees

**Edit** I think I can ask better (no code needed at all in this case). So the question in general is: how to use an Expression tree to build a call to a generic method `(Select<TEntity,TResult>` in my case) when `TResult` is created at runtime? Ignore all the code and text below, that was unclear version of the question, left it to not confuse those who answered.

I need an example how to build an Expression tree for a "Select" call. The problem is that I don't know the result type at compile time (it can be defined by user through some GUI in runtime). Here is some code of how I'm trying to do this (remember I can't use any generics)

```
class Pet {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using this class in Main:

```
List<Pet> list = new List<Pet>();                
Expression eList = Expression.Constant(list);
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Pet), "p");
MethodInfo method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("CreateObject", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var properties = typeof(Pet).GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.Name == "Name"); //will be defined by user
Expression selectorBody = Expression.Call(method, Expression.Constant(properties));
Expression selector = Expression.Lambda(selectorBody, pe);
Expression res = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Select", new[] { typeof(Pet), CreateType(properties) }, eList, selector);
```

What I'm trying to do is create a Type at runtime using Reflection.Emit (method "CreateType" in code above, it is used in some of my projects and looks fine) and somehow pass it to call to "Select", but I get exception:

> No generic method 'Select' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments.

Any suggestions?

**Upd** my real problem is building an Expression tree for a "Join" call for runtime types which is more complicated, so i decided to ask about "Select", because I'm having the same exception in the last line (Expression.Call(...))

**Upd2** included my helper methods and edited main code, however this is not the main problem.

```
static Type CreateType(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties) {
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = CreateTypeBuilder("ResultDynamicAssembly", "ResultModule", "ResultType");
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties) {
            CreateAutoImplementedProperty(typeBuilder, propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        }
        return typeBuilder.CreateType();
    }

    static object CreateObject(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties) {
        Type type = CreateType(properties); 
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post mode of your code? If the expression tree you're building is complex, it's nearly impossible to speculate on what may be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify this problem by removing the dynamic type from the equation. You can reproduce the same issue with the code below, which does exactly the same thing, but without the dynamic type.

```
static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Pet>();
        var eList = Expression.Constant(list);
        var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Pet), "p");
        var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("CreateObject", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var properties = typeof(Pet).GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.Name == "Name"); //will be defined by user
        var selectorBody = Expression.Call(method, Expression.Constant(properties));
        var selector = Expression.Lambda(selectorBody, pe);
        var res = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Select", new[] { typeof(Pet), CreateType(properties) }, eList, selector);
    }

    private static Type CreateType(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties)
    {
        return typeof (DynamicType);
    }

    private static object CreateObject(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties)
    {
        var type = CreateType(properties);
        return  Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }

    class Pet
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class DynamicType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So the problem is the method signature of CreateObject. Since its return type isn't the dynamic type, the lambda isn't valid. You can see this by changing the type of `CreateObject`.

```
    // this works fine
    private static DynamicType CreateObject(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties)
    {
        var type = CreateType(properties);
        return  (DynamicType) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
```

Since you're dealing with a dynamic type, you need to build an expression to cast the result of `CreateObject` to your dynamic type. Try using something like this:

```
        // create dynamic type
        var properties = typeof(Pet).GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.Name == "Name"); //will be defined by user
        var dynamicType = CreateType(properties);

        // build expression
        var list = new List<Pet>();
        var eList = Expression.Constant(list);
        var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Pet), "p");
        var createObjectMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod("CreateObject", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var createObjectCall = Expression.Call(createObjectMethod, Expression.Constant(properties));
        var castExpression = Expression.Convert(createObjectCall, dynamicType);
        var selectorExpression = Expression.Lambda(castExpression, pe);
        var res = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Select", new[] { typeof(Pet), dynamicType }, eList, selectorExpression);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the DynamicType from your suggestion cannot be declared explicitly in my case. Consider the following scenario: Customer class with properties Name, Phone, Country, Id, user can select any of them to be included in new type (using checkboxes for example) and my goal is to create this type at runtime and use it in calls to generic methods

Comment: I understand. The code above simply demonstrates that the problem doesn't stem directly from your use of a dynamic type. Add the `Expression.Convert()` call as shown above, and your problem will be fixed. If it is not, we still need more details.

Answer (score -1):

Create a factory for each type. You know what the source so it is really simple:

```
interface PetResultFactory<T>
{
    string TypeName {get; }
    List<T> Transform(IEnumerable<Pet> pets);
}
```

You have to register all possible types in container and show the registered types on the UI for the users. When a user selects one you know how to create that type becouse it is described in the factory.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is specifically related to building the expression tree. The unknown type is not really an essential part of the question.